# How to teleport the players to a defined place?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make a Skywars minigame, and I need to teleport the players to an island. I don't know what to do, I really want to make this minigame, I'm in 1.16.5 Minecraft Java Edition.

I've tried:

```
tp @p @r[type=armor_stand]
```

but it's not working.

Comment: Please, refrain from adding all information in title. A title should summarize your question.

Answer (score 2):

Use can use tags with multiple command block.

| # | `command` | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | `tag @r add island_teleport`(you can replace island_teleport with antything | `impulse` |
| 2 | `execute if tag=island_teleport tp <island_coordinates xyz>` | `repeating` |
| 3 | `tag @e remove island_teleport` | `chain` |

Answer (score -1):

You can teleport them to a specific location, such as "X=0, Y=0, Z=0."

Thus: `tp @p 0 0 0`

Comment: Thanks, but, i'm trying to make them teleport to random islands

Comment: Oh, ok then. I think maybe try out spigot to make a minigame if you know java.

Comment: thank you very much!